# Mount "/" andriod in pc for scan with av

Tags: file-system, mount, antivirus

**I want a method for scan all andriod system from my pc** with a antivirus, for example I've a backup with CMW, but the problem is that i need extract "tar" files and delete virus, then repack tar...

Do you know how can I **mount "/" files of andriod to my pc ?**

**Note:** I have root with busybox, but the virus is powerfull, he is with many files in /system /etc /data ... and others... I could flash it, but i need delete files with av... I've scanned the tar files, and eset nod32 found more than 50 infected files

**Another Note:** Factory-Reset isn't not way, because the virus is in /etc, /data, /system/ and anothers...**

Thank you very much.
Greetings!

Comment: I don't know if a PC-Antivirus can scan and remove Android viruses... My advice would be a complete factory reset if you don't have any important data on your phone that you didn't back up. You can always browse and export your file from old Nandroid backups with an app, for example this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore&hl=de

Comment: You should remove those malwares before doing a backup! If your phone is rooted, just install BusyBox and I'll show how to remove them. Only data partition can be mounted to be seen in PC

Comment: Ty dude, but factory restore not work for advanced virus, because its are in /system and /data and /etc... etc... could flash the device but i need remove it with av

Comment: @esQmo The av have detected 50+ viruses in the tar files of backup... I have root and busybox... but its is very hard, because the names are strange

Comment: The better way is to remove them manually or automatically by a tools. Or install system remover apps and unista all malwares then make a backup

Comment: Safest way is to factory-reset and then install a clean ROM. Everything else is prone to errors. No need to say to not restore stuff from the current state (to not have the malware return).

Comment: @Izzy Factory-reset NOT WORK, The virus is in /etc, /system, /data, and others..

Comment: @Milor123 read again: I wrote *factory-reset **and then install a clean ROM***. Installing the ROM overwrites `/system` and others. Depending on the recovery used, you could even do a format before that.

Comment: @Izzy This won't work on Samsung devices flashed through Odin, unless you check NAND clear all option. The malwares will still there. The best way I think, is removing them manually as one can do for bloatwares then install a clean ROM.

Comment: And pray you didn't miss a thing, @esQmo – well, another reason I won't buy a Sammy device. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Izzy I won't, I'm careful. And besides, malwares package names are easily identifiable. Using system apps make things easier than using a command terminal.